# ¿Cómo programar interfaz gráfica siendo ciego?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, interfaz-gráfica, ide, accesibilidad

Soy ciego de nacimiento y estoy estudiando la carrera de ingeniería de sistemas en la universidad.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo programar la interfaz gráfica de una aplicación en Android Studio. He buscado tutoriales y encontré varios que, por ejemplo para agregar un botón, lo arrastras hacia el lugar donde quieres que esté y ya automáticamente se te agrega.

En mi caso, al no ver, esto es imposible ya que mi lector de pantalla no está capacitado para hacer ese tipo de trabajos. Entonces mi pregunta es **¿cómo podría hacer yo para programar interfaces gráficas sin ver?**

Comment: Olvídate de arrastrar y soltar. Intenta programar directamente la interfaz a través del fichero xml.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, esta pregunta es muy interesante, pero tal y como está redactada es bastante amplia. Voy a intentar editarla para que sea más concreta (centrándome en Android Studio que es lo que comentas), pero sería bueno que la revisaras y editaras para hacerla más específica o puede acabar cerrada como muy amplia o basada en opiniones. Lee [ask] y completa  el [tour] para más información.

Comment: A mí siempre se me ha hecho demasiado texto inútil el que se usa en andrid standard con interfaces definidas por xml, por ello programo mis interfaces mediante [Dukescript](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#7151306) que me permite hacer HTML para las interfaces y enlazarla con el backend Java mediante [tag:knockoutjs] y generar código multiplataforma, incluido android nativo si así lo deseas

Comment: Hola @RodrigoCondori en el caso de desarrollo para android, actualmente no existe una forma desde la IDE para apoyarte, te sugiero activar TTS en tu dispositivo de desarrollo y de esa forma conocer la distribución de tus vistas en la pantalla.

Answer (score 12):

En el caso para desarrollar una interfaz gráfica por el momento no hay algún proyecto formal, en este caso como consejo te sugiero usar las opciones de accesibilidad que ofrece el sistema operativo, por ejemplo en el caso de Windows:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/13810/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-accessibility

Por ejemplo podría usar el Zoom en toda la pantalla el cual te ayudaría si tienes un porcentaje de visibilidad.

[image: Usar match_parent para maxima visibilidad]

o puedes activar el narrador

[image: Narrator lee texto en la pantalla]

para de esta forma revisar la información de la **documentación oficial relacionada a crear Interfaz de usuario en Android**, los cuales te serán de gran ayuda:

- **[interfaz de usuario](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html?hl=es)**
- **[Cómo crear una interfaz de usuario sencilla](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui?hl=es-419)**

**Un tip para ir sabiendo como esta siendo creada tu interfaz de usuario es activar el TTS (Text to Speech) en tu dispositivo con el cual desees desarrollar para de esta forma puedas escuchar que elementos que se están agregando a tu UI agregando una descripción mediante `android:contentDescription`.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFIlhqK2PmU

---

Incluso además de programar una aplicación, **es importante ayudar a crear aplicaciones que todos podamos usar**, incluidas las personas con algún tipo de discapacidad visuales, motora o auditiva.

**Añadiendo funciones de accesibilidad para usuarios ciegos y con discapacidad visual.**

Escucha el video de Victor Tsaran

[Resumen de accesibilidad](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility?hl=es)

**[Hacer las apps más accesibles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps)**

> Las aplicaciones de Android deben aspirar a ser utilizadas por todos,
> incluidas las personas con discapacidades.

> Las discapacidades comunes
> que afectan el uso de una persona de un dispositivo Android incluyen
> ceguera o baja visión, ceguera al color, sordera o discapacidad
> auditiva y habilidades motoras restringidas. Cuando desarrolla
> aplicaciones con la accesibilidad en mente, mejora la experiencia del
> usuario, especialmente para los usuarios con estas discapacidades. En
> la mayoría de los casos, hacer que su aplicación de Android sea más
> accesible no requiere una reestructuración extensa del código.

> Más bien, significa trabajar con los detalles sutiles de cómo los usuarios
> interactúan con su aplicación y proporcionar comentarios adecuados a
> los usuarios en función de sus interacciones. Este documento presenta
> pautas para mejorar la accesibilidad de su aplicación. También enumera
> los recursos que proporcionan detalles adicionales e información
> relacionada con las características de accesibilidad en Android.

En este caso por ejemplo a la hora de desarrollar podemos hacer uso de las aplicaciones mediante [TalkBack](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6283677?hl=en) o [Magnification](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006949?hl=en) mediante las cuales podemos maximizar la aplicación o incluso escuchar las descripciones al enfocar los elementos definidos en la UI, para estas descripciones debemos definir mediante `android:contentDescription` en cada vista un texto que indique el funcionamiento de la misma

```
<EditText
   ...
   android:contentDescription="@string/writeinfo"
   .../>
<Button
   ...
   android:contentDescription="@string/sendinfo"
   .../>
```

---

En el sitio en inglés podemos encontrar una pregunta similar:

[Programación para Android como ciego.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382130/programming-for-android-as-a-blind-person)

Comment: Amigo, de qué te sirve poner imágenes si no introduces un valor en el atributo ```alt```. La persona que pregunta no ve con claridad tu respuesta. Te sugiero que la modifiques.

Answer (score 2):

Intento explicar cómo se hacen las interfaces de usuario en android aunque, aviso, que no soy muy experto.

Básicamente cuando arrastras y sueltas un objeto en el diseñador de Android Studio, o cualquier IDE, lo que ocurre es que el objeto se inserta en un fichero que define el layout. Luego este fichero se referencia en la activity que se ejecuta y lo que se ha diseñado se muestra en la pantalla del dispositivo.

A grosso modo, en el manifest de la aplicación definimos todas las activities que vamos a usar y la que es la primera, de entrada. Algo así:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="X"
    android:targetSdkVersion="Y" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission-group android:name="android.permission-group.STORAGE"></uses-permission-group>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SplashScreen" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".InitActivity" />
</application>
```

Esto es algo bastante esquemático.

En la activity llamamos el layout:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.init_layout);
        // ... etc.
    }
}
```

Como ejemplo pongo SplashScreen que es el punto de entrada del manifest.

Y lo que nos falta es el propio fichero xml del layout. Pongo un ejemplo con un botón que es lo que se pide en la pregunta pero esto es solo a modo de ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/button.back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Para el caso el botón tiene estilo aplicado pero esto no es relevante. A lo que voy es que esto es lo que realmente define la disposición de los objetos en la pantalla. A partir de aquí habría que buscar un tutorial ya que esto es bastante amplio.

Saludos.

P.D.
A petición de @RuslanLopez añado este enlace de tutorial de [UI en android](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts)

Comment: ¿Si no puede ver,  como pudiera realizar lo que comentas en tu respuesta?, solo es un ejemplo para realizar una aplicación, el cual no es completo y tiene algunos detalles.  El OP pregunta " ¿cómo podría hacer yo para programar interfaces gráficas sin ver?"

Comment: @Elenasys yo creo que la respuesta si va orientada a lo que pide el OP. Dictar el código al lector de pantalla para que escriba lo que el IDE generaría de forma automática.

Comment: JYass si consideras que ayudaría, entonces faltaría pedir los permisos manualmente, configurar el build.grade en caso de requerir alguna dependencia o si esta dependencia marca clases repetidas. Definir minSdkVersion=x targetSdkVersion=y no funcionaría y ahora debe definirse dentro del build.gradle. El estilo "@style/button.back", ¿donde se definer?. Incluso el AndroidManifest.xml es incorrecto

Comment: @Elenasys si, ciertamente se deben definir dichas configuraciones para una respuesta más completa.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev yo he sido el que ha borrado los comentarios (no solo los tuyos). Fueron reportados por un tercero y se eliminó la conversación. No es cuestión de elites o castas, se busca el respeto mutuo y una conversación ordenada. Lee el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) para más información.

Comment: hola @EvgeniEnchev, puedes agregar la liga al tutorial por favor? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts

Comment: @RuslanLópez, no entiendo qué es lo que me pides. ¿Dónde quieres que agrege y qué? ¿El enlace que proporcionas? ¿Dónde?

Comment: la liga al tutorial, sí, y en la respuesta que hiciste con el propósito de complementarla.